# Clicking on pie chart slice changes the next slice to white

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

The problem is when I click on pie chart slice, the next slice changes the color to white.

The following link shows an example

[image]

```
mChart = (PieChart) layout.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
mChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);
mChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
mChart.setHoleRadius(58f);
mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
```

What's the problem?

Comment: which version of the libary are you using? This is a bug in Version 2.0.9, please update to current 2.1.1

Comment: I'm using  version 2.1.1 .

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Which device are you using? I cannot reproduce the issue.